# using a loop to define onClickListeners

Tags: android, loops, onclicklistener

I have the following code:

```
        imageButtonArray[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, GeneralSubject.class);
                intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", numberOfMoviesArray[0]);
                intent.putExtra("titleName", titleNamesArray[0]);
                intent.putExtra("numOfIndex", "0");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        imageButtonArray[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, GeneralSubject.class);
                intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", numberOfMoviesArray[1]);
                intent.putExtra("titleName", titleNamesArray[1]);
                intent.putExtra("numOfIndex", "1");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

it works fine.

When I try to change that code to:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
            imageButtonArray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, GeneralSubject.class);
                intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", numberOfMoviesArray[i]);
                intent.putExtra("titleName", titleNamesArray[i]);
                intent.putExtra("numOfIndex", String.valueOf(i));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

the LogCat says:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length:2, index:2

what does it mean? how do I fix it?

Comment: On which line does it throw the exception?

Comment: @ElefantPhace No no no no no.

Comment: <= 2 is what would cause this error, < 2 should be fine

Comment: when does it happen? When you click on the button?

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your project!

Comment: See my answer try to define the bounds with the size of your array imageButtonArray.length.

Comment: Jorgesys, it didn't help.

Comment: the line that causes the problem is
    intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", numberOfMoviesArray[i]);

Comment: It happens when I click the button

Comment: @MaorYichyeh with the code you've provided, I don't see how it's possible for the first version to work and the second version to crash on that line. Can you please carefully check whether the code for each version is exactly what's in your project?

Comment: by the way, all this code is inside the onCreate function. The variable i is declared outside of it (if that matters...)

Comment: I doubled check by pasting the code I posted into my project. It still fails on the line I mentioned in the loop version and succeeds in the other version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are  keeping `i` as class member (My assumption is based on the fact that I cant see it declared as final elsewhere) By the time the loop ends `i` would be `2`. When you click on the `Button`,

```
  private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

       private int mNumberOfMovies;
       private String mTitleName;
       private int mIndex;

       public MyOnClickListener(int numberOfMovies, String titleName, int index) {
               mNumberOfMovies = numberOfMovies;
               mTitleName  = titleName;
               mIndex = index;
       }

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, GeneralSubject.class);
            intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", mNumberOfMovies);
            intent.putExtra("titleName", mTitleName);
            intent.putExtra("numOfIndex", mIndex);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
  }
```

and in your activity

```
for (i=0;i<imageButtonArray.length;i++){ //Change this line
        imageButtonArray[i].setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(numberOfMoviesArray[i], titleNamesArray[i] ,i));
}
```

Comment: But if this works, then that means that the array has length less than 2. And if that were the case, then the OP's *working* first version would also throw an exception.

Comment: that depends on how java implements closure with class member. OP is keeping i as class member. My assumption is based on the fact that I cant see it declared as final elsewhere. By the time the loop ends i would be 2. If the op clicks on the button, it will access a posion that does not exists. But of course, that depends on how java implements the closure with class member and, under what circumstances the exception happens  @chiastic-security

Comment: @Blackbelt, I get the following compilation error: No enclosing instance of the type Algebra is accessible in scope. How do I handle it? Algebra is in the same package.
And as for the array's length - even when it has the length of 5, it still produces the same problem.

Comment: @MaorYichyeh I forgot to mention that MyOnClickListener has to be an inner class of your activity Algebra

Comment: It still fails on the putExtra lines... with a NullPointerException this time

Comment: I dunno, update the question with the changes you made and post the stacktace

Comment: I now realize that if I change the line:
    intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", numberOfMoviesArray[i]);
to
     intent.putExtra("numberOfMovies", "3");

it still fails on that line, also in the inner class suggestion